# How do i change background color using radio buttons in tables. 4 colors(white, red, yellow, green) to each radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make 4 radio buttons with the colors of (white, red, yellow, green) its gonna take up full background in the table row

i can only make it 1 color on all 4 buttons to work not 4 seperate colors in 1 table row

```
<tr>
            <td>

                   <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">

            <br>
            text text</td>
    </td>


            <td>
                   <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">
            <br>
           text text</td>


            <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">
            <br>
            text text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>



            <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">
            <br>
            text text
        </td>


                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">
            <br>
                text text
        </td>


            <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">
            <br>
                text text text 
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


            <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">>
            <br>
           text text
            </td>


            <td>
                   <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();">
            <br>
            text text
            </td>


            <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="white" name="drone" value="white" onclick="white();" checked>
                    <input type="radio" id="red" name="drone" value="red" onclick="red();">
                    <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="yellow();">
                    <input type="radio" id="green" name="drone" value="green" onclick="green();"> 
            <br>
            text text
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function white()
    {
        document.getElementById("table").addEventListener("click",changeRadioColor);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
    function red()
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
    function yellow()
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    }
    function green()
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
    }
```

4 radio buttons with 4 different colors changing the background when checked in 1 table row

Comment: Where is your javascript with the functions `white()`, `red()`, etc.?

Comment: <script>
        function white()
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="white";
        }
        function red()
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
        function yellow()
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        }
        function green()
        {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly setting the backgroundColor of the entire body, and you have a lot of repeated code. This can be reduced to a single function to which you must pass the element being clicked so that you can get the color value from it and find the correct element to style.
If I understand correctly, you want the containing `<td>`'s background to match the value of the selected radio button, try this:

```js
window.setBgColor = function(radio) {
  console.log(radio.closest('td'));
  radio.closest('td').style.backgroundColor = radio.value;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <br> text text
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <br> text text
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <br> text text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <br> text text
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <br> text text
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="white" onclick="setBgColor(this)" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="red" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="yellow" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <input type="radio" name="drone" value="green" onclick="setBgColor(this)">
      <br> text text
    </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

This is very flexible, in that you can add a new radio to any `<td>` with any color just change it's value, but keep `onclick="setBgColor(this)"` and it should work. 
**Note**, a better solution would be to add a common class to all the radios and assign an event listener for the class, but that is a different question.

Comment: I removed the id properties from the inputs, as they were not needed, and invalidly re-used.

Answer (score 0):

Change your inputs to

```
<input type='radio' value='red' class='color-input' name='color'>
<input type='radio' value='blue' class='color-input' name='color'>
```

Between your scripts tag place

```
// Get all the radio buttons by their class name(color-input)
var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".color-input")

// For each of them, when their inputs are updated(clicked) apply their color (this.value) to the background
radioButtons.forEach(function(el) {
  el.oninput = function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
  };
});
```

Because they are inputs you aren't necessary "clicking" them, but updating their input. That's why its "on input" and not "on click"

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you're not using jQuery. I'll update the response.

Answer (score 0):

A pure jQuery ($) solution would look like:

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
     $(this).closest('td').attr("style", "background-color:" + $(this).val());
   });
```

or

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
 $(this).closest('td').css("background-color", $(this).val());
});
```